# I am getting a null parameter in the constructor when attempting to use parameters with junit4

Tags: junit, junit4

Basically, I am attempting to experiment with junit4 parameters.  I am not clear why I am getting null as the parameter to the LongMathAddTest constructor.

Thanks
GC

```
   @RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
    public class LongMathAddTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data()
    {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{new Long[]{1L,3L,4L,5L},1},{new Object[]{2l,3l,6l,78l,90l},30},{new Object[]{3l,78l,4l,3l},4},{new Object[]{4l,545l,56l,3l},3},{new Object[]{4l},3},{null,null}};
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    private Long numbers[];
    private Long total;

    public LongMathAddTest(Long numbers[],Long total) {
        this.numbers=numbers;
        this.total=total;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because your last parameter group is `{null,null}` ?

Also When I try to run your code as is, I got IllegalArgumentExceptions for type mismatches, you have to make sure your 2nd parameter is also a long (currently it is an int) and the `Object[]` should all be Long[]

It might be easier to spot errors and make the code more legible by splitting your data across multiple lines:

```
 Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
                          {new Long[]{1L,3L,4L,5L},1},
                          {new Object[]{2l,3l,6l,78l,90l},30},
                          {new Object[]{3l,78l,4l,3l},4},
                          {new Object[]{4l,545l,56l,3l},3},
                          {new Object[]{4l},3},
                          {null,null}
                    };
```

Comment: Technically, the {null,null} is valid and works.  You can pass null to a function with a parameter of Long[].  However, you are right about that second parameter. It was type int, not long.